# Create Child Record without modify all Data permission

Tags: permissions, profile

need suggestion for below query,

i have two object with master detail relation(Object A is Parent, Object B is Child)

in one of my profile i have Object A is only Read access,and
want to create object B record.

when i try to create record it gives insufficient access error.

it will work fine if i give modify all permission for object A for same profile.

other than this solution, do we have any solutions.

Thanks

Comment: ad without sharing in your class and give it a try.

Comment: How are you creating these objects? by code? by vf or by standard pages?

Comment: Hi Tushar, i can't use withoutsharing, other than this we have any other solution

Comment: hi salesforcesmarty, im creating records from controller using VF page

Answer (score 4):

When creating a field with a Master-Detail relationship, you can select the access requirements for editing the master record in the sharing section. To have edit access to the child with read only access to the parent, you need to change the default "read/write" to "read".
[image]