# Do we need Edit access on Parent record if they have Rollup Summary

Tags: master-detail, configuration, roll-up-summary

I have a child object which has a Master detail relationship with Account. There are some rollup fields on account.
Now whenever I'm trying to create a new child record using a user who does not have edit access on Account, I'm getting below error.

> insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Do I also need Edit access on Parent record to make it work?
Please note I don't have any kind of automation active like trigger, process builder and workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a field with a Master-Detail relationship, you can select the access requirements for editing the master record in the sharing section. To have edit access to the child with read only access to the parent, you need to change the default "read/write" to "read".

This post helped to resolve my issue:
[Create Child Record without modify all Data permission](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105013/create-child-record-without-modify-all-data-permission/114394)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like sharing issue. Since it's a Master-Detail relationship, that means sharing access for the child custom object will be set by the parent (Account) record. Since you say this user does not have Edit access to that Account record, then they would also not have edit access for the child record either.

Please keep in mind that the User might have Edit **permissions** on the custom object (and field level access), but that does not automatically mean they have **sharing** access to any of the individual records. Basically think of creating/editing child records in a Master-Detail relationship as being the same thing as updating the parent record itself.